# Número máximo de linhas de um import Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, dump

Bom, estou fazendo o import que contém todos os meus banco de dados, pois troquei de computador, exportei do antigo e estou querendo importar para o novo, mas ao importar recebo um erro: `"tempo limite alcançado, envie novamente o arquivo para continuar"`. Algo do tipo, já aumentei o limite de upload, o tempo máximo de execução, fiz o tutorial deste site: http://pt.stealthsettings.com/importa-baze-de-date-mari-sql-schimband-marimea-limita-de-upload-2048-kib-din-phpmyadmin.html
Mas não obtive resultado, alguém pode me ajudar, a quantidade de linhas desse meu arquivo `.sql` é de **635.374**, lá tem todos os estados, cidades, e bairros. Acho que deve ser pela grande quantidade de linhas, alguém tem uma sugestão? Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ficou meio confuso sua pergunta mas se eu entendi bem, você está tentando importar sua base de dados antiga para seu novo servidor atráves do phpmyadmin e está recebendo um timeout. Você pode aumentar o tempo limite de seu PHP em seu servidor novo se tiver acesso ao php.ini isso ira contornar o problema ou se tiver acesso ao shell gerar um dump de sua base de dados no servidor antigo e importar via linha de comando no servidor novo.

Aqui tem uma página com uma explicação de como se utiliza o mysqldump :
http://sistemas.cekurte.com/blog/mysqldump-backup-de-base-de-dados-mysql/
Espero que isso seja útil.

Comment: Cara vlw, eu já sabia que isso existia, tinha até lembrado, mas fui teimoso de querer mexer com phpmyadmin. Setei as variáveis de ambiente e fiz o import pelo CMD, olha, nem demorou muito para fazer o import, vlw pela dica!

Comment: Tranquilo meu Rei disponha !!! Estamos juntos !